# MariaDB CONNECT engine to read external file

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-connect-engine

I would like to read an external file into MariaDB using the CONNECT engine. However, when trying to read from the file, I get an error message:

```
MariaDB [test]> create table test ( name varchar(100), team varchar(100) ) engine=CONNECT table_type=CSV file_name='/tmp/data.csv' header=1 sep_char=',' quoted=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.24 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from test;
ERROR 1296 (HY000): Got error 174 'Open() error 13 on /tmp/data.csv: Permission denied' from CONNECT
```

Checking the filesystem permissions gives me:

```
divingt@grisu ~ $ ls -l /tmp/data.csv
-rw-rw-rw- 1 divingt divingt 1658 Dec 31 13:59 /tmp/data.csv
```

So everybody should be able to read and write from the file.

Also in MYSQL the permissions allow for everything:

```
MariaDB [test]> SHOW GRANTS;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I run a Linux Mint system.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Consider using `LOAD DATA` instead of Connect?

Comment: Yes, that works. However, the point was to use connect engine, because I also want to use it for reading XML data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the reason was that `apparmor` prevented `mysqld` from reading from reading the file. Disabling it (or changing the permissions) solved the problem.